# Auto enable published article from registered users in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, publish

I have created a site where registered users can publish articles.
Is there a way to make the articles they publish be enabled automatically without me, as administrator, have to check if there are new articles submitted.

EDIT 1: Found a solution by setting the mysql default value of state to 1 from 0. But, is this a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to publish is controlled by the edit.state permission. You would want to give edit.state allow for registered for either all of content or just for specific categories they are allowed to publish in.

Comment: Elin, Can you please eloborate this answer. Where can I found this configuration to change?

Comment: Go to the article manager, click on options, go to the permissions tab. Or go to the permissions tab for the category.  That's not a programming question however, that's a question better answered by going to joomla.stackexchange.com or reading the joomla user documentation.https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

Comment: Thanks Elin. Actually, I am editing the php files for my customization in the mean while I just keen to know the where the feature in admin UI.